# JQuery hover selector works in Chrome dev tools but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to set a hover event for elements matching a selector. I have written the following line of code to do this.

```
$(".myclass > [myattr=50]").hover(()=>console.log("d"))
```

If I open up Chrome dev tools and run this line of code, and then hover over the appropriate element on the page, the console logs the letter "d". However, if I run this line of code in javascript then the hover selector does not work. What might be causing this issue? How can I debug it?

Note: I am using Jquery as an escape hatch in an application that uses react very heavily. I understand that this is not standard. For my specific use case, I really need Jquery.

Comment: So the selector does not find elements when you run it....

Comment: no it does find elements, in code and in dev tools

Comment: You are accessing the elements before they exist on the page. So either you need to wait for document ready or bind it when the elements are added. Not knowing your code it is hard to know why.

Comment: The weird thing is that I change CSS using `$(".myclass > [myattr=50]").css(...` it works so I know the elements are on the page

Comment: But React may in the meantime replace the elements with new ones looking the same (including your CSS change) so your listener will be useless because it was attached to the old one. Try `$('body').on('hover', '.myclass > [myattr=50]', () => console.log('d'))` instead

Comment: Well you should NOT be using DOM with react. Jquery + react is a bad idea. Add mouseenter and mouseleave in the React code.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score -3):

As @epascarello said it could not find element or the element could be recreated after your code, basically its all about timing if you dont have an event or anything to wait before your code, you can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to delay your code execution. Start with small timeout and try to increase until it works.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(".myclass > [myattr=50]").hover(()=>console.log("d")); }, 500);
```

Comment: Calls just need to be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {/* code here */})`

Comment: You dont event have a solution :)

Comment: "Start with small timeout and try to increase until it works." << and then if the computer is slow because some other program is using more CPU, or it's an older computer or whatever, the code randomly stops working :-|

Comment: i also said  if you dont have an event or anything to wait before your code so waiting for a spesific time is the last chance

Comment: It is a guessing game if it is loaded with your solution, there are better solutions than a random timer. Issue here is OP is using React and really should not be using jQuery in general. React has hooks that can be used to bind the events, but really should just be react code and not a mixture.